# Fixed read-only folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to copy or move folders and files in my C# application, but the folders are **Read-Only**, and they cannot be disabled, since when I try, it's enabled again. I tried many solutions, but not worked... Yes, I am administrator with all rights. I tried disable Read-only in script too, but don't work.

```
const int CopyBufferSize = 64 * 1024;
    public void CopyFile(string source, string destination)
    {
        //File.Copy(source, destination);
        //Stopwatch swTotal = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        using (var outputFile = File.Create(destination))
        {
            using (var inputFile = File.OpenRead(source))
            {
                // we need two buffers so we can ping-pong
                var buffer1 = new byte[CopyBufferSize];
                var buffer2 = new byte[CopyBufferSize];
                var inputBuffer = buffer1;
                int bytesRead;
                IAsyncResult writeResult = null;
                while ((bytesRead = inputFile.Read(inputBuffer, 0, CopyBufferSize)) != 0)
                {
                    // Wait for pending write
                    if (writeResult != null)
                    {
                        writeResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                        outputFile.EndWrite(writeResult);
                        writeResult = null;
                    }
                    // Assign the output buffer
                    var outputBuffer = inputBuffer;
                    // and swap input buffers
                    inputBuffer = (inputBuffer == buffer1) ? buffer2 : buffer1;
                    // begin asynchronous write
                    writeResult = outputFile.BeginWrite(outputBuffer, 0, bytesRead, null, null);
                }
                if (writeResult != null)
                {
                    writeResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                    outputFile.EndWrite(writeResult);
                }
            }
        }
        //swTotal.Stop();
        //Console.WriteLine("Total time: {0:N4} seconds.", swTotal.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    }
```

I tried with

```
File.Copy(source, destination);
```

too.

Thank you.

Comment: @Nalaka, the code is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[more details..](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=VS.100).aspx)

```
var fileName = "sourceFile.txt";
var source = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileName);
var destination = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, fileName);

File.Copy(source, destination);
```

OR

```
File.Copy(@"someDirectory\someFile.txt", @"otherDirectory\someFile.txt");
```